# how to map css and js file from jsp file in spring mvc

Tags: css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring mvc. I want to add css and js files in jsp. It's a spring mvc framework.
This is my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml code

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/css/**"/>
```

SpringDemo is my project name folder. I keep my file in 
SpringDemo/WebContent/resources/css and in the same location i keep my js file also 
SpringDemo/WebContent/resources/js

Below code is jsp file called RegistrationForm.jsp

```xml
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

    <link href="WebContent/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/SpringDemo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42640779/6711884

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like your resource mapping is not correct, your css and js files are under "/resources" folder right? then the mapping should be

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

The inclusion of the elements in the view have been answered multiple times in stackoverflow itself. You can refer [unable to use resources like css/js in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786182/unable-to-use-resources-like-css-js-in-spring-mvc/34788957#34788957)
or [How to include js and CSS in JSP with spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276603/how-to-include-js-and-css-in-jsp-with-spring-mvc?rq=1)

Comment: I tried those. but it doesn't work. if you know please let me know. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking:

Resource Mapping:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

Adding JS/CSS in jsp pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css"/>">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/app.min.js"/>"></script>
```

**Note**: All of the JS/CSS files must be under `src\main\webapp\resources` directory.

And if you have added Security, then you need to add this:

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
```