# Bootstrap files are not loading with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

when i do spring configuration in web.xml it doesn't load bootstrap files request will go to controller class but  if i do servlet configuration in web.xml everything is works fine how this is possible

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="">
            <title>Login Page</title>
           <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
        <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href=../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form role="form"  action="login" method="post">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="userName" type="text" autofocus>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                                       <!--   <a href="pages/AdminHome.jsp" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a> -->
                                        <input type="submit" value="login" /> 
                                   <br>

                                   <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Registration Yourself
                                         <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="StudentByAdmin.jsp">Student</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="ParentsByAdmin.jsp">Parent</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="TeacherByAdmin.jsp">Teacher</a></li>
                                           </ul>
                                        <p><a href="#">Forgot your password ?</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                 </fieldset>                            
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
            <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
            <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
            <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

spring configuration in web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- create ds , only app start.. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <!-- map all action to ds -->
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: show us both web.xml  files

Comment: where shall i put the code

Comment: Edit your question and add it in similar way as the one currently

Comment: anyone help me please

Comment: thats not spring configuration problem bootstrap files problem why because i given cdn for css its working

Comment: You need maven resource plugin which will put all your css/js under `src/main/resources` and then follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959932/how-to-map-css-and-js-file-from-jsp-file-in-spring-mvc/34968392#34968392). Alternately you can use front-end build tool like gulp or grunt to minify/uglify/concat your js/css and put it under resources folder.

Comment: this is not maven project